# Installation and configuration of nginx on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

I have been trying to install nginx web server on my local machine (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). But the installation could not be completed. It's giving error that systmd is not found.

Is it possible to install the server (nginx) on local machine like Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. If yes, please how can I resolve this?

Comment: How did you try to install nginx? This should not occur if you just install the system purchase.